# Send Basic Auth with axios.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

i need some help with axios.all, actually i'm doing a multiple request in the github api, but i need to send a basic auth and i dont know how to do this with axios.all, here's my code.

```
    const axios = require('axios');
    const lista = require('./lista.json')
    const credentials = require('./credentials')
    const fs = require('fs')

    const userObject = {}
    const userArray = []

    for (i = 0; lista.length > i; i++){ 
        function getAllData () {
            axios.all ([
                axios.get( `https://api.github.com/repos/${lista[i].user}/${lista[i].repo}/stats/contributors`),
                axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${lista[i].user}/${lista[i].repo}/commits`),
                axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${lista[i].user}`)
            ])
            .then(axios.spread((res1, res2, res3) => {
                console.log(res1.data[0].total)
                console.log(res2.data[0].commit.author.date)
                console.log(res3.data.name)
}))
```

i know that with single requesition i can sand a auth: { username: xxx, password : xxx}, but how can i do this in axios.all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add [axios defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults) in following way

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
```

Comment: Really don't get it how to do it, actually i did this way in a single request 
axios.get(api3, {
            auth: {
                username: credentials.username,
                password: credentials.token
            }
        })

i tried to use your advice but they keep returning that i'm not autheticaded

Comment: tried again, and worked like that : axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.github.com/';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer AUTH_TOKEN' thank you!